# Error running microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1 on selfhosted runner in nektos/act on mac M1

Tags: .net, msbuild, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, nektos-act

I am trying to build a .net 4.8.1 solution using msbuild with github actions and run it locally on my mac M1 using nektos/act.

When I execute the step Actions/setup-dotnet@v3 to setup .NET core it works.

When I execute the step microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1 to setup msbuild, it FAILS!.

error:
##[error]MSBuild.exe only works for Windows. I have tried various options, but none work.

Please advise.

````
on:
  workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  BuildOnWindows:
    runs-on:  windows-latest #windows-2019 
    env:
      RUNNER_OS: x64
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: 'Test os'
        run: echo $RUNNER_OS

      # Other build steps for Windows
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'  # Specify the .NET SDK version you need

      - name: Add msbuild to PATH
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
        with:
          #msbuild-architecture: arm64 #x64
          vs-version: '[15.1]'```
````

Comment: You may not need to install MSBuild separately. There is an embedded copy of MSBuild in the `dotnet` tool. Use the `dotnet msbuild` subcommand. There is a macOS build of MSBuild but it appears the `microsoft/setup-msbuild` task is Windows only.

Comment: Tried manually dotnet msbuild from the solution folder. I get error: The ASP.NET compiler is only available on the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.

Comment: I missed that you stated "I am trying to build a .net 4.8.1 solution". ".net 4.8.1" is .NET Framework and .NET Framework is Windows only. You can't build a .NET Framework solution on macOS. You need to use .NET (aka .NET Core). You are, apparently, setting up .NET 6.

Comment: I was testing .NET 6, but really need 4.8.1. I thought that the CLI command: act -W .github/workflows/build-dotnetapplication.yml  -P windows-latest=-self-hosted would spin up a windows container within which I could run the microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1 step